# In Three.js how to get geometry's vertex colors from a json file exported from Blender?

Tags: three.js, blender, vertex

What I want to achieve is to color the geometry's vertices in a visual way and render ONLY its vertices in Three.js.

[image: Cube in Blender in Vertex Paint mode]

What I want to get:

[image: cube with vetext colored in Three.js]

I use Blender to mark the color but can't get the vertex colors in Three.js.

My steps:

1. Make a cube in Blender. Paint each of the 8 vetices a different color in "Vertex Paint" mode in Blender
2. Export the cube to json file via the Bender addon [Three.js Blender Export](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender)
3. Load the json file in Three.js as below:

   ```
   (new THREE.JSONLoader()).load('cube.json', function(geometry) {
       console.log(geometry.colors); //an empty array ? why?
   })
   ```

content of cube.json :

```
{
    "materials":[],
    "colors":[16725291,16748308,16770898,16720850,5562367,6553492,11599643,2046719,16777215],
    "faces":[131,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,131,4,7,6,5,0,4,5,6,7,131,0,4,5,1,0,0,4,7,1,131,1,5,6,2,0,1,7,6,2,131,2,6,7,3,0,2,6,8,3,131,4,0,3,7,0,4,0,3,5],
    "vertices":[1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1],
    "metadata":{
        "generator":"io_three",
        "materials":0,
        "colors":9,
        "type":"Geometry",
        "vertices":8,
        "faces":6,
        "version":3
    }
}
```

Is there a way in Three.js to get the vertex colors I paint? or is there another visual method to color the vertices and render it out in Three.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering the vertices of a model as points in three.js is easiest using [THREE.PointsMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/PointsMaterial.html). This material supports per-vertex colors, read from the *colors* property of the geometry.

However, the tricky part is that while your cube.json contains exactly this set of colors, the THREE JSONLoader interprets them as per-face-vertex colors (for face rendering). We have to convert them back to per-vertex colors in order to render them as part of the vertex point cloud.

```
// Convert face-vertexcolors to .colors array
geometry.colors = [];
for (var faceIndex = 0; faceIndex < geometry.faces.length; faceIndex++) {
    var face = geometry.faces[faceIndex];
    geometry.colors[face.a] = face.vertexColors[0];
    geometry.colors[face.b] = face.vertexColors[1];
    geometry.colors[face.c] = face.vertexColors[2];
}

// Render mesh as THREE.POINTS
var pointsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: 40,
    sizeAttenuation: true,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors // This triggers  actual usage of the colors
});
var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, pointsMaterial);
mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 250;
scene.add(mesh);
```

[Working example](https://www.eponalabs.com/experiments/JSONLoaderVertexColors/json_loader_vertex_colors.html): 
[image: Colored vertices]